# Read lines from FILE

Tags: c, input

I would like to know what is the best way to read a lines from files, given I have
a file, that I'm promised that it would be as followed:

```
type
string table
color
string brown
height
int 120
cost
double 129.90
```

each time, one word then I would have 2 words.

I know that fscanf returns the value of the numbers of var it scans, and that's
why I have problem here, because one time the line has 1 argument and the next line it would have 2.

always the first line is only a char*, not longer then 10, and then the next is has 3 options..
if it is written an int then the number followed would be an int, as well as if it a double or a string.

thank you.

Comment: In a loop, read a line. Then read another line. From the second line use `sscanf` to read two *strings*. If the first is equal to `"double"` then use e.g. [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof), else if it's `"int"` then use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). Iterate the loop.

Comment: In my opiniom you could use an `fgets` to read line `NULL` to stop it at the end of file. To storage the strings i suggest you `sscanf` and parsing it with `%31[^\n]s` that read the string until the \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the structure of file i think it can be grouped into a struct. And fscanf can be used like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 100

typedef struct Node {
  char name[SIZE];
  char type[SIZE], value[SIZE];
} Node;

int main() {
  FILE *pFile = fopen("sample-test.txt", "r");
  if(pFile == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in reading file\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  Node nodes[SIZE];
  int nRet, nIndex = 0;

  // Just to make sure it reads 3 tokens each time
  while((nRet = fscanf(pFile, "%s%s%s", nodes[nIndex].name, 
                       nodes[nIndex].type, nodes[nIndex].value) == 3)) 
    nIndex++;

  for(int i = 0; i < nIndex; i++)
    printf("%s %s %s\n", nodes[i].name, nodes[i].type, nodes[i].value);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After reading the file, you can check in your structure array to find your desired `int`, `double` depending upon the value of `name` using `sscanf` as pointed by Some Programmer Dude.

Comment: Not a bad approach at all, but `fscanf` has it's downsides. A `while ((nRet = fscanf(pFile, "%s%s%s", ...) == 3)` instead of the `do {...} while (..);` would avoid the excess newline output. A `fgets` and then a `strchr` for *space* with a counter is another alternative. It doesn't matter much if the input is guaranteed.

Comment: Much better, I'll tweak the format of the long line for you.